# CodeIgniter on localhost issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well< I try to run CodeIgniter on my localhost with MAMP. I've changed base_url in config.php on `$config['base_url']   = 'http://localhost:8888/codeigniter';`
Also I've created blog.php as in tutorial I use:

```
<?php
class Blog extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
?>
```

But, when I go to `http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/index.php/blog/`, there is output of my index.php ('test' - string) but there is no hello world there, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your blog class located within the controllers directory and named the same as the class?

Comment: Yep it is in application/controllers and it's named blog.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the biggest breaking change between Codeigniter 1.7 -- which many tutorials are based on -- and Codeigniter 2 is the first line of code in the controllers and models

```
class Blog extends Controller {
```

change that to

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
```

same for models

```
class Donotmakemodeljokes extends CI_Model {
```

Comment: changed but for some reason the result is the same=(

Comment: in my index.php there is only echo of "test", may be this is a problem? should I include smth in it?

Comment: Actually the first test should always be the default CI welcome page which is also the default route. does that work?